# Optimization of matplotlib stem plot

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, optimization, plot

I'm trying to produce a Stem plot using the 'matplotlib.pyplot.stem' function. The code works but it is taking over 5 minutes to process.

I have a similar code within Matlab that produces the same plot with the same input data almost instantly.

Is there a way to optimize this code for speed or a better function I could be using?

The arguments for the stem plot 'H' and 'plotdata' are 16384 x 1 arrays.

```py
def stemplot():

    import numpy as np
    from scipy.fftpack import fft
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    ################################################
    # Code to set up the plot data

    N=2048
    dr = 100

    k = np.arange(0,N)

    cos = np.cos
    pi = np.pi

    w = 1-1.932617*cos(2*pi*k/(N-1))+1.286133*cos(4*pi*k/(N-1))-0.387695*cos(6*pi*k/(N-1))+0.0322227*cos(8*pi*k/(N-1))

    y = np.concatenate([w, np.zeros((7*N))])

    H = abs(fft(y, axis = 0))
    H = np.fft.fftshift(H)
    H = H/max(H)
    H = 20*np.log10(H)
    H = dr+H 
    H[H < 0] = 0        # Set all negative values in dr+H to 0

    plotdata = ((np.arange(1,(8*N)+1,1))-1-4*N)/8
    #################################################

    # Plotting Code

    plt.figure
    plt.stem(plotdata,H,markerfmt = " ")

    plt.axis([(-4*N)/8, (4*N)/8, 0, dr])    
    plt.grid()
    plt.ylabel('decibels')
    plt.xlabel('DFT bins')
    plt.title('Frequency response (Flat top)')
    plt.show()


    return
```

Here is also the Matlab code for reference:

```matlab
N=2048;
dr = 100;
k=0:N-1

w = 1 - 1.932617*cos(2*pi*k/(N-1)) + 1.286133*cos(4*pi*k/(N-1)) -0.387695*cos(6*pi*k/(N-1)) +0.0322227*cos(8*pi*k/(N-1));

H = abs(fft([w zeros(1,7*N)]));
H = fftshift(H);
H = H/max(H);
H = 20*log10(H);
H = max(0,dr+H); % Sets negative numbers in dr+H to 0


figure
stem(([1:(8*N)]-1-4*N)/8,H,'-');
set(findobj('Type','line'),'Marker','none','Color',[.871 .49 0])
xlim([-4*N 4*N]/8)
ylim([0 dr])
set(gca,'YTickLabel','-100|-90|-80|-70|-60|-50|-40|-30|-20|-10|0')
grid on
ylabel('decibels')
xlabel('DFT bins')
title('Frequency response (Flat top)')
```

Comment: Can you make this a [MCVE]? Without knowing what your `w` is, this code cannot be run.

Comment: Also, `return` is a statement, not a function. No need for the `()` after it.

Comment: No need for it at all in this particular case ;-)

Comment: Apologies, I cut down from what was a larger code and accidentally left out the 'w' variable. I'll edit the question and include just the arguments for the plot.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7969) and [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9560) github issue. This seems to be a known issue.

Comment: I could repeat one of the comments in the second issue: With 16384 points, are you sure that a stem plot is what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no need for a `stem` plot here, since the markers are anyway made invsibible and would not make sense due to the large number of points.

Instead the use of a LineCollection may make sense. This is [how matplotlib will do it in a future version](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9565/commits/71c456fec3841c107be0647d20b5cc3d8912bd0f) anyways - see [this PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9565). The code below runs within 0.25 seconds for me. (This is still slightly longer than using `plot`, due to the large number of lines.)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import matplotlib.collections as mcoll

N=2048
k = np.arange(0,N)
dr = 100

cos = np.cos
pi = np.pi

w = 1-1.932617*cos(2*pi*k/(N-1))+1.286133*cos(4*pi*k/(N-1))-0.387695*cos(6*pi*k/(N-1))+0.0322227*cos(8*pi*k/(N-1))

y = np.concatenate([w, np.zeros((7*N))])

H = abs(fft(y, axis = 0))
H = np.fft.fftshift(H)
H = H/max(H)
H = 20*np.log10(H)
H = dr+H 
H[H < 0] = 0        # Set all negative values in dr+H to 0

plotdata = ((np.arange(1,(8*N)+1,1))-1-4*N)/8


lines = []
for thisx, thisy in zip(plotdata,H):
    lines.append(((thisx, 0), (thisx, thisy)))
stemlines = mcoll.LineCollection(lines, linestyles="-",
                    colors="C0", label='_nolegend_')
plt.gca().add_collection(stemlines)


plt.axis([(-4*N)/8, (4*N)/8, 0, dr])    
plt.grid()
plt.ylabel('decibels')
plt.xlabel('DFT bins')
plt.title('Frequency response (Flat top)')

plt.show()
```

Comment: You beat me once more :) I had a solution using `vlines` which is also very fast.

Comment: @Thomas If your solution uses something other than a LineCollection and if it is significantly faster than the 5 seconds from the question, why not post it here as well?

Comment: Done. I don't know about faster, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the code works much better than the .stem method!

I think initially I was just trying to translate the matlab code directly, in this instance a direct comparison was not the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can simulate a stem plot in the format you desire using `ax.vlines`. Writing a small function,

```
def make_stem(ax, x, y, **kwargs):
    ax.axhline(x[0],x[-1],0, color='r')

    ax.vlines(x, 0, y, color='b')

    ax.set_ylim([1.05*y.min(), 1.05*y.max()])
```

And then altering the the relevant lines in your example as follows:

```
    # Plotting Code

##    plt.figure
##    plt.stem(plotdata,H,markerfmt = " ")

##    plt.axis([(-4*N)/8, (4*N)/8, 0, dr])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    make_stem(ax, plotdata, H)
```

produces the plot more or less instantly. I don't, however, know whether this is faster or slower than the answer of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.

Comment: The solution from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48302491/4124317) below takes 0.25 seconds, while this solution takes 0.23 seconds on my computer. Not a large difference, but apparently still a bit faster.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your response, I tested this code and it works just as fast as the one above, either method is suitable.